# cant install any package on ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, operating-systems, kernel

```
root@osboxes:~# apt install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 332 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.9
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda3
I: (UUID=0678741e-d2a3-4fda-bc4e-e3ceb5d4d297)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.8.9 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@osboxes:~#
```

I'm running Ubuntu on my VirtualBox, I've been using the OS for a while now everything seemed fine. But today I tried to install a few packages I kept getting this weird error. The same error seemed to pop up on anything I tried to install using apt-get or apt install commands. I left images of the command line:

[command line picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itfP0.png)

df and ls -l /boot commands

[image: df command output]

[image: ls -l/boot command]

Comment: Can you provide the output of "df; L's -l /boot" - I wonder if /boot partition is full.

Comment: Are these two separate commands? I could run the full thing. Are you asking for the df command alone?  @davidgo

Comment: Either is fine. The ";" means execute one command after the other. Note it should be "ls" not "Ls" ... Cellphone autocorrect.

Comment: @davidgo added both images in the question

Answer (score 0):

the problem was caused because the boot partition was full and did not have any space. I fixed it by simply increasing the size of the boot partition. (note that if you have a swap partition to the right of the boot partition you need to delete it before being able to increase the size of the boot partition)